# Bengali font problem in Blogger.com

Tags: fonts

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my PC. There is no apparent problem in Bengali font rendering in websites such as techtunes.com.bd and somewhereinblog.com but whenever I switch to my blog on blogger.com, the bengali fonts appear incorrectly. Is there any solution to this problem? I love using Ubuntu but I also need to update my blog frequently.

Here is the link to my blog:
http://islamisforlife.blogspot.com/2012/12/islam-is-for-life-index.html

Note: This problem persists in google chrome as well as in firefox. I have properly installed iBus Avro on my PC and it seems to work perfectly.